# Receiving and transmitting data with socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm having trouble with receiving and sending data with Python's socket. In my script I need to listen to incoming data in socket and reading a FIFO file for a response and send it with socket when I find \n. I created separate thread for reading FIFO and it works but sometimes it is really slow. Is it possible to do both things in a main thread? My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

from optparse import OptionParser, make_option
import os
import errno
import sys
import socket
import uuid
import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import time

from threading import Thread
try:
  from gi.repository import GObject
except ImportError:
  import gobject as GObject

class ArduinoFifo:
    fifofile = -1
    OUT_PIPE_FILE = '/tmp/ble_pipe_out'

    def removeFile(self, filename):
        try:
            os.remove(filename)
        except OSError as e: # this would be "except OSError, e:" before Python 2.6
            if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: # errno.ENOENT = no such file or directory
                print(e)
                raise # re-raise exception if a different error occured

    def createFifo(self):
        print('removing pipe file\n')
        self.removeFile(self.OUT_PIPE_FILE)

        print('making pipe\n')
        try:
            os.mkfifo(self.OUT_PIPE_FILE, 0777)
        except OSError as err:
            print (err)
            raise

    def openFifo(self):
        print('waiting to open pipe\n')
        try:
            self.fifofile = os.open(self.OUT_PIPE_FILE, os.O_WRONLY) # | os.O_NONBLOCK)
        except OSError as err:
            print (err)

    def writeFifo(self, data):
        try:
            if (self.fifofile == -1):
                openFifo(self)
            os.write(self.fifofile, data)
        except OSError as err:
            print (err)

class FIFOReader(Thread):
    def __init__(self, server_sock):
        super(FIFOReader, self).__init__()
        self.server_sock = server_sock
        self.daemon = True
        self.received_msg = ""
        self.cancelled = False
        print('remove in fifo')
        try:
            os.remove("/tmp/ble_pipe_in")
        except OSError as e: # this would be "except OSError, e:" before Python 2.6
                if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: # errno.ENOENT = no such file or directory
                        print(e)
                raise

        print('create in fifo')
        try:
            os.mkfifo("/tmp/ble_pipe_in", 0777)
        except OSError as err:
                print (err)
            raise

        print('open in fifo')
        try:
            self.fifofile = os.open("/tmp/ble_pipe_in", os.O_RDWR)
        except OSError as err:
                print (err)
        print('fifo in opened')

    def run(self):
        while not self.cancelled:
            print("READING")
            self.received_msg += os.read(self.fifofile, 1)
            print("read: %s\n" % self.received_msg)
            if "\n" in self.received_msg :
                print("Sending Message...")
                self.server_sock.send(self.received_msg)
                self.received_msg = ""

    def cancel(self):
        self.cancelled = True

myfifo = ArduinoFifo()

class Profile(dbus.service.Object):
    fd = -1

    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                    in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Release(self):
        print("Release")
        mainloop.quit()

    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                    in_signature="", out_signature="")
    def Cancel(self):
        print("Cancel")


    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                in_signature="oha{sv}", out_signature="")
    def NewConnection(self, path, fd, properties):
        global received_msg
        self.fd = fd.take()
        print("NewConnection(%s, %d)" % (path, self.fd))


        server_sock = socket.fromfd(self.fd, socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_sock.setblocking(1)

        myfifo.openFifo()
        infifo = FIFOReader(server_sock)
        infifo.start()

        print('enter recv loop\n')
        try:
            while True:
                data = server_sock.recv(1024)
                #print("received: %s" % data)
            if data:
                    myfifo.writeFifo(data)
            #if data == "h":
                #server_sock.send("Hello!\n")
        except IOError as err:
            print (err)
            pass

        server_sock.close()
        print("all done")
        os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)



    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                in_signature="o", out_signature="")
    def RequestDisconnection(self, path):
        print("RequestDisconnection(%s)" % (path))

        if (self.fd > 0):
            os.close(self.fd)
            self.fd = -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

    bus = dbus.SystemBus()

    manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez",
                "/org/bluez"), "org.bluez.ProfileManager1")

    option_list = [
            make_option("-C", "--channel", action="store",
                    type="int", dest="channel",
                    default=None),
            ]

    parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list)

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    options.uuid = "1101"
    options.psm = "3"
    options.role = "server"
    options.name = "Edison SPP Loopback"
    options.service = "spp char loopback"
    options.path = "/foo/bar/profile"
    options.auto_connect = False
    options.record = ""

    profile = Profile(bus, options.path)

    mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()

    opts = {
            "AutoConnect" : options.auto_connect,
        }

    if (options.name):
        opts["Name"] = options.name

    if (options.role):
        opts["Role"] = options.role

    if (options.psm is not None):
        opts["PSM"] = dbus.UInt16(options.psm)

    if (options.channel is not None):
        opts["Channel"] = dbus.UInt16(options.channel)

    if (options.record):
        opts["ServiceRecord"] = options.record

    if (options.service):
        opts["Service"] = options.service

    if not options.uuid:
        options.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())

    manager.RegisterProfile(options.path, options.uuid, opts)

    myfifo.createFifo()

    mainloop.run()
```

EDIT: I think the problem is in writing data to FIFO or receiving incoming data from socket because in my code in C I've got this delay when I want to read a data from the input FIFO using fgets function.

EIDT2: I use this to instantly receive a message and sends a response one after another

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the issue has to do with the separate thread. "Threads" in Python aren't necessarily OS-level threads but could just be operations the main OS-level thread processes asynchronously. [In cPython, which most people use, this is how they work.](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) But I do see a couple of possible issues:

I'm not familiar with some of these libs, but `os.read(self.fifofile, 1)` stands out. If you use the builtin `open()` (not the one in `os`) or `BufferedReader`, this would be buffered and therefore ok. But `os.open` is a low-level call that doesn't buffer reads or writes, so you're actually reading 1 byte at a time from the file handle this way, which isn't a good idea as it can cause slowdowns for a variety of hard-to-trace reasons. You should either use a higher level library for this or do the buffering yourself.

Secondly, your `+=`'ing of the read input to the message string repeatedly is going to be slow if your Python interpreter is creating a new string internally each time. So you could be looking at O(N^2) where N is message size time complexity for something that should be O(N). It depends on your interpreter, so to make things portable, you should be appending to a list instead.

Unrelated, but if you don't know whether your FIFO file is text, you shouldn't open it in text mode or else you'll run into errors. Strings only allow valid text bytes, UTF-8 if it's Py3 and I think ASCII if it's Py2, and you'll get an error if you receive, say, `0x00`.

Hope this helps.